# Prompted multiple times to exit menu

Tags: powershell

trying to write a PowerShell script which uses a menu and sub menus. When I first run the code and press Q to quit the 'Main Menu', it quits back to console. However, if I go into 'Menu 1' then quit back to 'Main Menu' and then quit once more to the console, it runs this code again `$input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"`

I've tried looking for different methods of quitting the menu, but haven't found much luck as of yet. Any advice would be appreciated

See example code below:

```
function showMainMenu {
    function showMenu1 {

        do {
            Write-Host "================ Menu 1 ================"

            Write-Host "1: Option 1"
            Write-Host "Q: Back to the main menu"

            $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
            switch ($input) {
                '1' {
                    Write-Host "Some text"
                } 'q' {
                    showMainMenu        
                }
            }
                
        }
        until ($input -eq 'q')

    }

    function showMenu2 {
        Write-Host "================ Menu 2 ================"

        Write-Host "1: Option 1"
        Write-Host "Q: Press Q to quit"
        
        do {
            $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
            switch ($input) {
                '1' {
                    Write-Host "Some text"
                } 'q' {
                    showMainMenu
                }
            }
        }
        until ($input -eq 'q')

    }

    Write-Host "================ Main Menu ================"
        
    Write-Host "1: Menu 1"
    Write-Host "2: Menu 2"
    Write-Host "3: Press Q to quit"
        
    do {
        $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
        switch ($input) {
            '1' {
                showMenu1
            } '2' {
                showMenu2
            } 'q' {
                return
            }               
        }
        pause
    }
    until ($input -eq 'q')  
}

showMainMenu
```

Comment: For one thing, **don't use `$input`** as self-defined variable because it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#input)

Comment: Thanks @Theo I've changed it now.

Comment: In the question it is unchanged..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its stuck in a loop due to using `do{}until()`.

```
function showMainMenu {
    function showMenu1 {

        do {
            Write-Host "================ Menu 1 ================"

            Write-Host "1: Option 1"
            Write-Host "Q: Back to the main menu"

            $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
            switch ($input) {
                '1' {
                    Write-Host "Some text"
                } 'q' {
                    showMainMenu        
                }
            }
                
        }
        until ($input -eq 'q')

    }

    function showMenu2 {
        Write-Host "================ Menu 2 ================"

        Write-Host "1: Option 1"
        Write-Host "Q: Press Q to quit"
        
        do {
            $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
            switch ($input) {
                '1' {
                    Write-Host "Some text"
                } 'q' {
                    showMainMenu
                }
            }
        }
        until ($input -eq 'q')

    }

    Write-Host "================ Main Menu ================"
        
    Write-Host "1: Menu 1"
    Write-Host "2: Menu 2"
    Write-Host "3: Press Q to quit"
        

        $input = Read-Host "Please choose an option"
        switch ($input) {
            '1' {
                showMenu1
            } '2' {
                showMenu2
            } 'q' {
                break
            }               
        }
}

showMainMenu
```

Comment: Same error here: **don't use `$input`** as self-defined variable because it is an [automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1#input)

Comment: Have you tried to open a new runspace? its not giving me any error using $input.

Comment: If you keep ignoring those basic rules, you will script yourself into serious, difficult to solve problems. Just use different variable names and use the automatic ones for what they are designed for.